# Correct way to register for pre-shutdown notification from C++

Tags: c++, winapi, service, notifications, shutdown

I write a local service application using C++ and I can't find the correct way of registering for a pre-shut-down notification (for OS later than Windows XP). I believe that SERVICE_CONTROL_PRESHUTDOWN notification has been added since Vista, but when you call SetServiceStatus do we need to specify:

```
dwServiceStatus.dwControlsAccepted = SERVICE_ACCEPT_PRESHUTDOWN;
```

or

```
dwServiceStatus.dwControlsAccepted = SERVICE_ACCEPT_SHUTDOWN | SERVICE_ACCEPT_PRESHUTDOWN;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot accept both a shutdown and a preshutdown if your service is correctly coded. The documentation explicitly states this.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683241(v=vs.85).aspx:

Referring to `SERVICE_CONTROL_PRESHUTDOWN`:

> A service that handles this notification blocks system shutdown *until the service stops* or the preshutdown time-out interval specified through SERVICE_PRESHUTDOWN_INFO expires.

In the same page, the section about `SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN` adds:

> Note that services that register for SERVICE_CONTROL_PRESHUTDOWN notifications *cannot receive this notification because they have already stopped*.

So, the correct way is to set the `dwControlsAccepted` to include either `SERVICE_ACCEPT_SHUTDOWN` or `SERVICE_ACCEPT_PRESHUTDOWN`, depending on your needs, but not to both at the same time.

But do note that you probably want to accept more controls. You should *always* allow at least `SERVICE_CONTROL_INTERROGATE`, and almost certainly allow `SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP`, since without the latter the service cannot be stopped (e.g. in order to uninstall the software) and the process will have to be forcibly terminated (i.e. *killed*).

Comment: Very good answer. Thank you. Microsoft should've hired you to write their documents :) I would understand them then...

Comment: One follow-up question though. Say, if I'm processing the SERVICE_CONTROL_PRESHUTDOWN (or SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP, or just starting the service) when I periodically call SetServiceStatus() to update the status with SCM, when SERVICE_STATUS::dwCurrentState is set to SERVICE_STOP_PENDING (or SERVICE_START_PENDING), what shall I specify in the SERVICE_STATUS::dwControlsAccepted then?

Comment: Can you please confirm this?

Comment: In SERVICE_STOP_PENDING you shouldn't accept any more controls (except, maybe `SERVICE_CONTROL_INTERROGATE` if you are really pedantic) since you are in the process of shutting down, and that's an irreversible state. In SERVICE_START_PENDING the same applies - either accept nothing or just `SERVICE_CONTROL_INTERROGATE`. But do note that your service should spend the *minimum amount of time* necessary in `SERVICE_START_PENDING` and not perform any lengthy/unnecessary initialization.

Comment: You know I'm gonna ask, what's the "minimum amount of time"?

Comment: I know you will, but the answer is "it depends". The general guideline is "don't do anything that is not strictly necessary for your service startup to complete".

Comment: Just a little note: it's not an error to accept both `SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN` and `SERVICE_CONTROL_PRESHUTDOWN` (i.e. in the call to `SetServiceStatus()`, which returns 1). So it's simpler to just 'or' the preshutdown flag in case it's determined at runtime. Your service will only receive the pre-shutdown notification.

Answer (score 2):

As noted by the commenters above, you will need to choose from either SERVICE_ACCEPT_SHUTDOWN or SERVICE_ACCEPT_PRESHUTDOWN (Vista or later). If you are using SERVICE_ACCEPT_PRESHUTDOWN, you will need to register your service with the SCM using [RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685058%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of RegisterServiceCtrlHandler else you will not be receiving the pre-shutdown notifications. The handler prototype also changes from Handler to [HandlerEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683241%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Another point to note is that handling pure shutdown events is limited to 5 seconds in Windows Server 2012 (and presumably Windows 8), 12 seconds in Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008, 20 seconds in Windows XP before your service is killed while stopping. This is the reason why you may need the pre-shutdown notification. You may want to change this at \\HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\WaitToKillServiceTimeout.

Comment: I think the WaitToKillServiceTimeout controls the pre-shutdown timeout. Windows will kill the SCM if it take longer than this regardless of what any services are doing, if I'm reading this correctly.

From Windows Internals:

"When Csrss encounters the SCM process, it also notifies it that the system is shutting down but employs a timeout specific to the SCM....The SCM’s timeout value resides in the HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\WaitToKillServiceTimeout registry value, and it defaults to 12 seconds."

Answer (score 1):

In the comment from alexpi there is a key piece of information. I found that the service handling PRESHUTDOWN needs to update the service status with a new checkpoint number (repeatedly) before WaitToKillServiceTimeout has elapsed. My server was configured to 5000 ms and my service only updated every 12000 ms, and the server went into the SHUTDOWN phase, which caused my attempt to stop another service to return the error that the shutdown was in progress.

Answer (score 0):

These two notifications seem to be different as I get it from the documentation. If what you need is really to enable your service to recieve preshutdown notification, you should go with: `dwServiceStatus.dwControlsAccepted = SERVICE_ACCEPT_PRESHUTDOWN;` But if you also want to enable your service to receive shutdown notifications, you should go with your second option.

Comment: Thanks. What I'm getting from the documentation is that SERVICE_ACCEPT_PRESHUTDOWN replaces SERVICE_ACCEPT_SHUTDOWN since Vista due to limitations of the latter. Am I wrong in my assumption?

Comment: @ahmd0 can you point me to the surce you are refering to? I have not seen this anywhere

Comment: Accepting both PRESHUTDOWN and SHUTDOWN is meaningless - the proper response for a service that registers for and receives PRESHUTDOWN notifications is to exit; therefore such a service will never receive a SHUTDOWN notification, even if it asks for it. The details are on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683241(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I do not see how does this contradict to what I said in my answer.

Comment: You said "But if you *also* want to enable your service to receive shutdown notifications, you should go with your second option" the second option being to register for both PRESHUTDOWN and SHUTDOWN notifications. But a service **cannot** receive *both* PRESHUTDOWN and SHUTDOWN notifications if it's properly written since the correct response is to terminate on a PRESHUTDOWN notification, which means it won't be running to see a SHUTDOWN notification. Si it's one or the other - PRESHUTDOWN or SHUTDOWN. Not both.

Comment: I agree with what you say, but still my answer is correct. Truth is a service *should not* register for both PRESHUTDOWN and SHUTDOWN, but indeed if the OP goes with his second option, he will register for both just as I say. I agree that if the service is properly implemented this should never happen, but still that is what it will result into.

Comment: @NikB. What do you guys mean by "exit"? Do I need to specifically call exit() at the end of the shut-down notification processing, or is it just enough to set service status to SERVICE_STOPPED? But if I do the latter, what shall follow the SetServiceStatus() call?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771222/effect-of-exit-function-in-windows-service-programs). Just calling exit is not a safe option.

Comment: @ahmd0 No, do not call exit as izomorphius pointed out. I meant that once the service receives the PRESHUTDOWN notification, it must do whatever processing it needs to do, and must then set its status to SERVICE_STOPPED and the process must terminate. *If* your service is properly written the process should terminate automatically when the service state is set to SERVICE_STOPPED.

Comment: Yeah, but what code should I put after doing SERVICE_STOPPED? I can't just have it hanging, can I?