# Windows C service not writing to file in PreShutdown event

Tags: c, windows, windows-services

I am working on a Windows Service written in C code.

In the service initialization code I have registered to a **SERVICE_ACCEPT_PRESHUTDOWN** event like this:

```
gSvcStatus.dwControlsAccepted = SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP | SERVICE_ACCEPT_PRESHUTDOWN;
```

In the service control handler I have writen the logic to write to a file in the **SERVICE_CONTROL_PRESHUTDOWN** event like this:

```
DWORD WINAPI SvcCtrlHandler(DWORD dwCtrl, DWORD eventType, void *eventData, void *context)
{
    if (dwCtrl == SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP)
    {
        gSvcStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
        gSvcStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOPPED;
    }
    else if (dwCtrl == SERVICE_CONTROL_PRESHUTDOWN)
    {
        char sentence[] = "Hello World";
        FILE *fptr;
        fptr = fopen("C:\\test\\program.txt", "w");
        if (fptr == NULL) {
            printf("Error!");
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(fptr, "%s", sentence);
            fclose(fptr);
        }
        gSvcStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
        gSvcStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOPPED;
    }
    SetServiceStatus(g_ServiceStatusHandle, &gSvcStatus);
    return NO_ERROR;
}
```

But after reboot, I am not able to see the file **program.txt** in **test** folder. Need help in fixing this issue.

**What else I have tried:**

I also tried writing to event Viewer using the **SvcReportEvent** function:

```
//
// Purpose: 
//   Logs messages to the event log
//
// Parameters:
//   szFunction - name of function that failed
// 
// Return value:
//   None
//
// Remarks:
//   The service must have an entry in the Application event log.
//
VOID SvcReportEvent(LPTSTR szFunction) 
{ 
    HANDLE hEventSource;
    LPCTSTR lpszStrings[2];
    TCHAR Buffer[80];

    hEventSource = RegisterEventSource(NULL, SVCNAME);

    if( NULL != hEventSource )
    {
        StringCchPrintf(Buffer, 80, TEXT("%s failed with %d"), szFunction, GetLastError());

        lpszStrings[0] = SVCNAME;
        lpszStrings[1] = Buffer;

        ReportEvent(hEventSource,        // event log handle
                    EVENTLOG_ERROR_TYPE, // event type
                    0,                   // event category
                    SVC_ERROR,           // event identifier
                    NULL,                // no security identifier
                    2,                   // size of lpszStrings array
                    0,                   // no binary data
                    lpszStrings,         // array of strings
                    NULL);               // no binary data

        DeregisterEventSource(hEventSource);
    }
}
```

Change done to **SvcCtrlHandler** function:

```
DWORD WINAPI SvcCtrlHandler(DWORD dwCtrl, DWORD eventType, void *eventData, void *context)
{
    if (dwCtrl == SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP)
    {
        SvcReportEvent((LPTSTR)TEXT("In function SvcCtrlHandler in condition SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP"));
        gSvcStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
        gSvcStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOPPED;
    }
    else if (dwCtrl == SERVICE_CONTROL_PRESHUTDOWN)
    {
        SvcReportEvent((LPTSTR)TEXT("In function SvcCtrlHandler in condition SERVICE_CONTROL_PRESHUTDOWN"));
        gSvcStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
        gSvcStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOPPED;
    }
    SetServiceStatus(g_ServiceStatusHandle, &gSvcStatus);
    return NO_ERROR;
}
```

**Observation:**

1. When I restart my computer, there is no Eventviewer log written
2. When I manually stop the service, a log is written into event viewer:

> In function SvcCtrlHandler in condition SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP

Note: Link I referred while writing the service: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/the-complete-service-sample?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Are you positive that you are setting the SERVICE_ACCEPT_PRESHUTDOWN flag in each call to SetServiceStatus? Also, I recommend adding SERVICE_ACCEPT_SHUTDOWN and the corresponding handler and seeing if that is called.

Comment: Hi. Yes, I have set the PRESHUTDOWN flag in each call to SetSerivceStatus. I also tried adding the recommended SHUTDOWN handler. Even this handler did not get called for some reason. I have also tried using just the SHUTDOWN handler, because some posts I read suggested that only one of SHUTDOWN/PRESHUTDOWN gets called. But for me neither of them are getting called.

Comment: Strange. Make sure that your call to SetServiceStatus() is successful and is not returning an error. What version of Windows is this?

Comment: Hi @CoreTech. I wanted to know if you could share with me a minimum working C based service for reference on how to handle SHUTDOWN / PRESHUTDOWN event. I am currently looking for a sample to do this, but I haven't found anything online that addresses my requirement.

Comment: Are you sure the account running the service has permission to write to the desired file?

Comment: Yes. I am able to write to Event viewer upon service Stop. But not able to write to evenviewer for shutdown/preshutdown. I also suspected that writing to file would have been the problem. But if I am able to write to event viewer in once case and not write in another case then the issue should be somewhere else I think.

Comment: Also, I added the same code to write to file in Stop Service section and the file was written. So - there is no permission problem.

Comment: @CoreTech "*Also, I recommend adding SERVICE_ACCEPT_SHUTDOWN*" - SERVICE_ACCEPT_PRESHUTDOWN and SERVICE_ACCEPT_SHUTDOWN can't be used together, see [Correct way to register for pre-shutdown notification from C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13329254/)

Comment: @GaneshKamath-'CodeFrenzy' please update your question to include a [mcve] demonstrating how your service runs, particularly how you initialize, manage, and use `gSvcStatus`.

Comment: While working on minimum reproducible example, I have fixed the issue. Please don't downvote. Already loosing points as bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting the answer that solved my problem

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <WinBase.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#define SVC_ERROR                              ((DWORD)0xC0020001L)

SERVICE_STATUS        gSvcStatus = { 0 };
SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE g_ServiceStatusHandle = NULL;
HANDLE                g_ServiceStopEvent = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

VOID WINAPI ServiceMain(DWORD argc, LPTSTR *argv);
DWORD WINAPI SvcCtrlHandler(DWORD dwCtrl, DWORD eventType, void *eventData, void *context);
DWORD WINAPI ServiceWorkerThread(LPVOID lpParam);

#define SVCNAME  _T("SampleService")

//
// Purpose: 
//   Logs messages to the event log
//
// Parameters:
//   szFunction - name of function that failed
// 
// Return value:
//   None
//
// Remarks:
//   The service must have an entry in the Application event log.
//
VOID SvcReportEvent(LPTSTR szFunction)
{
    HANDLE hEventSource;
    LPCTSTR lpszStrings[2];
    TCHAR Buffer[80];

    hEventSource = RegisterEventSource(NULL, SVCNAME);

    if (NULL != hEventSource)
    {
        StringCchPrintf(Buffer, 80, TEXT("%s failed with %d"), szFunction, GetLastError());

        lpszStrings[0] = SVCNAME;
        lpszStrings[1] = Buffer;

        ReportEvent(hEventSource,        // event log handle
            EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,   // event type
            0,                           // event category
            SVC_ERROR,                   // event identifier
            NULL,                        // no security identifier
            2,                           // size of lpszStrings array
            0,                           // no binary data
            lpszStrings,                 // array of strings
            NULL);                       // no binary data

        DeregisterEventSource(hEventSource);
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[])
{
    SvcReportEvent(_T("My Sample Service: Main: Entry"));

    SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY ServiceTable[] =
    {
        {SVCNAME, (LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION)ServiceMain},
        {NULL, NULL}
    };

    if (StartServiceCtrlDispatcher(ServiceTable) == FALSE)
    {
        SvcReportEvent(_T("My Sample Service: Main: StartServiceCtrlDispatcher returned error"));
        return GetLastError();
    }

    SvcReportEvent(_T("My Sample Service: Main: Exit"));
    return 0;
}


VOID WINAPI ServiceMain(DWORD argc, LPTSTR *argv)
{
    DWORD Status = E_FAIL;

    SvcReportEvent(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: Entry"));

    g_ServiceStatusHandle = RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx(
        SVCNAME, 
        SvcCtrlHandler, 
        NULL);

    if (g_ServiceStatusHandle == NULL)
    {
        SvcReportEvent(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: RegisterServiceCtrlHandler returned error"));
        goto EXIT;
    }

    // Tell the service controller we are starting
    ZeroMemory(&gSvcStatus, sizeof(gSvcStatus));
    gSvcStatus.dwServiceType = SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS;
    gSvcStatus.dwControlsAccepted = 0;
    gSvcStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_START_PENDING;
    gSvcStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
    gSvcStatus.dwServiceSpecificExitCode = 0;
    gSvcStatus.dwCheckPoint = 0;

    if (SetServiceStatus(g_ServiceStatusHandle, &gSvcStatus) == FALSE)
    {
        SvcReportEvent(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: SetServiceStatus returned error"));
    }

    /*
     * Perform tasks neccesary to start the service here
     */
    SvcReportEvent(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: Performing Service Start Operations"));

    // Create stop event to wait on later.
    g_ServiceStopEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
    if (g_ServiceStopEvent == NULL)
    {
        SvcReportEvent(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: CreateEvent(g_ServiceStopEvent) returned error"));

        gSvcStatus.dwControlsAccepted = 0;
        gSvcStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOPPED;
        gSvcStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = GetLastError();
        gSvcStatus.dwCheckPoint = 1;

        if (SetServiceStatus(g_ServiceStatusHandle, &gSvcStatus) == FALSE)
        {
            SvcReportEvent(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: SetServiceStatus returned error"));
        }
        goto EXIT;
    }

    // Tell the service controller we are started
    gSvcStatus.dwControlsAccepted = SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP | SERVICE_ACCEPT_PRESHUTDOWN;
    gSvcStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_RUNNING;
    gSvcStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
    gSvcStatus.dwCheckPoint = 0;

    if (SetServiceStatus(g_ServiceStatusHandle, &gSvcStatus) == FALSE)
    {
        SvcReportEvent(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: SetServiceStatus returned error"));
    }

    // Start the thread that will perform the main task of the service
    HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ServiceWorkerThread, NULL, 0, NULL);

    SvcReportEvent(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: Waiting for Worker Thread to complete"));

    // Wait until our worker thread exits effectively signaling that the service needs to stop
    WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);

    SvcReportEvent(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: Worker Thread Stop Event signaled"));


    /*
     * Perform any cleanup tasks
     */
    SvcReportEvent(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: Performing Cleanup Operations"));

    CloseHandle(g_ServiceStopEvent);

    gSvcStatus.dwControlsAccepted = 0;
    gSvcStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOPPED;
    gSvcStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
    gSvcStatus.dwCheckPoint = 3;

    if (SetServiceStatus(g_ServiceStatusHandle, &gSvcStatus) == FALSE)
    {
        SvcReportEvent(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: SetServiceStatus returned error"));
    }

EXIT:
    SvcReportEvent(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: Exit"));

    return;
}


DWORD WINAPI SvcCtrlHandler(DWORD dwCtrl, DWORD eventType, void *eventData, void *context)
{
    if (dwCtrl == SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP)
    {
        SvcReportEvent((LPTSTR)TEXT("In function SvcCtrlHandler in condition SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP"));
        gSvcStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
        gSvcStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOPPED;
    }
    else if (dwCtrl == SERVICE_CONTROL_PRESHUTDOWN)
    {
        SvcReportEvent((LPTSTR)TEXT("In function SvcCtrlHandler in condition SERVICE_CONTROL_PRESHUTDOWN"));
        gSvcStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
        gSvcStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOPPED;
    }
    SetServiceStatus(g_ServiceStatusHandle, &gSvcStatus);
    return NO_ERROR;
}


DWORD WINAPI ServiceWorkerThread(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    SvcReportEvent(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceWorkerThread: Entry"));

    //  Periodically check if the service has been requested to stop
    while (WaitForSingleObject(g_ServiceStopEvent, 0) != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
    {
        /*
         * Perform main service function here
         */

         //  Simulate some work by sleeping
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            char sentence[] = "Hello World";
            FILE *fptr;
            fptr = fopen("C:\\test\\program.txt", "a");
            if (fptr == NULL)
            {
                printf("Error!");
            }
            else
            {
                fprintf(fptr, "%s", sentence);
                fclose(fptr);
            }
            Sleep(3000);
        }
    }

    SvcReportEvent(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceWorkerThread: Exit"));

    return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}
```